# GooglePlay Violation of Deceptive Ads policy. How to issue a request to install a third-party application?

Tags: android-intent, google-play

An application is required to send an intent to a specific recipient.
This decision led to the removal of the application from the market.

Reason: Violation of Deceptive Ads policy.

Button "Print" -> GooglePlay

```
   protected void sendToPrint(Intent intent) {
    final String appPackageName = "........";
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    // check app installed
    PackageInfo pi = null;
    if (pm != null) {
        try {
            pi = pm.getPackageInfo(appPackageName, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (pi == null) {
        // go to install
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        }
    } else {
        // send to print
        intent.setPackage(appPackageName);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

How to minimally modify the code to meet the requirements?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
                .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_install, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

[Is it correct ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTgEs.jpg)
I am afraid that this, too, seems like something that cannot be done.
https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/ads/deceptive/

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like this
https://github.com/402d/DemoRawBtPrinter/commit/1bb45e5a8f9b24f2ad9cc902f2285fc376e8909c

Add customized AlertDialog
The app is back in GooglePlay. Now more than 48 hours in it.